# Has Many Through two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have two models of importance here. There's more models interacting with them too, but only these should be relevant.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trip
end

class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trip

  # has_many :images, through: :user
end
```

The commented out line gets me halfway there but I want to meet an additional condition of the image having the same Trip ID as the Mission.

```
  # has_many :images, through: [:user, :trip]
```

Using an array like some similar methods sometimes take, is invalid syntax.

```
   def images
     Image.where(user_id: user_id, trip_id: trip_id)
   end
```

Should I just do that? Or is there a better way to do it? I also tried with conditionals on the has_many but anything dynamic I put there was being called off of `Image::ActiveRecord_Relation`

Here are some sample records:

```
<User id=1>
<User id=2>
<Trip id=1>
<Trip id=2>
<Image id=1, user_id=1, trip_id=1>
<Image id=2, user_id=1, trip_id=1>
<Image id=3, user_id=1, trip_id=1>
<Mission id=1, user_id=1, trip_id=1>
<Mission id=2, user_id=2, trip_id=1>
<Mission id=3, user_id=2, trip_id=2>
```

So `Mission.find(1).images` gives back the 3 images, whereas 2 and 3 give an empty array.

Comment: How many models you have to connect with ? Image, Mission, User, Trip ? How those 4 types are related ?

Comment: User and Trip are simple models that could have no columns besides an ID. Both Image and Mission have relations where they belong to a user and belong to a trip. I want to get the Images that have the same two belong to associations as the mission does. So `Mission.find(1).images` should return the images that have the same user_id and trip_id. If I only needed them to match a user_id then I could simply do `has_many :images, through: :user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try like this

```
class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :trip
    has_many :images, ->(obj) { where("#{Image.quoted_table_name}.trip_id = ?", obj.trip_id)}, through: :user
    # or
    has_many :images, ->(obj) { where("#{Image.quoted_table_name}.user_id = ?", obj.trip_id)}, through: :trip
end
```

This obj represents the object of Mission class, so i have added the one more condition on images associations.

```
Mission.first.images.to_sql
#=> "SELECT \"images\".* FROM \"images\" INNER JOIN \"users\" ON \"images\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" WHERE (\"images\".trip_id = 1) AND \"users\".\"id\" = ?"
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for, I'm updating my question to try and be more clear

Comment: Works great! One thing though, I simplified it to just be `has_many :images, ->(obj) { where(trip_id: obj.trip_id) }, through: :user`

Comment: @TMP Thanks, :)
I had added that 'Image.quoted_table_name' just for remove an ambiguity of trip_id, because same column in under users table and we are joining it in our query.

Answer (score 0):

> A belongs_to association sets up a one-to-one connection with another model [...]

It looks like you could benefit making your image table have a `mission_id` instead of `user_id` and `trip_id` since then you could simply say

> - Image `belongs_to` Mission
> - Mission `has_many` Images
> - User `has_many` Images `through` Mission
> - Trip `has_many` Images `through` Mission

Comment: This is what I started off with, but I changed it because in some cases I wanted the image's trip_id to be nil, such as with a user's profile picture.