# ruby has many through two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Problem: In `enrollment.attendances.count(:id)` Enrollment must have access only to those attendances, that match it by both student_id and course_id.

Here are my 4 db dependancies:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
  has_many :attendances, through: :client
  has_many :attendances, through: :course
```

,

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :attendances
```

,

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :attendances
```

,

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
```

,

The schema of the model dependancies:
[image: model dependancies]

Comment: Isn't Enrollment  `has_many :attendances` ambiguous ?

Comment: the point is that in attendances/_form you can select only students, that are "enrolled" into the course. A student can have many attendances in one course, a student can be enrolled into a course only one time (made through model validation in enrollment.rb: `  validates_uniqueness_of :client_id, :scope => :course_id`)

Comment: i still dont quite understand what your question is, like @Santhosh said, your `has_many :attendances` is ambiguous, start renaming them like `students_attendances` and `courses_attendances`

Comment: do you still need a help?

Comment: I still don't get it how to set the enrollment-attendances dependancies in the models..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271961/has-many-through-two-models)

putting the following line in **enrollment.rb**

```
  has_many :attendances, ->(obj) { where("#{Attendance.quoted_table_name}.client_id = ?", obj.client_id)}, through: :course
```

perfectly solves the question

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the `object` from `Enrollment` by `student_id` and `course_id`

and then check whether it attended or not
then you could find the `count`.

```
@enrolls = Enrollment.where(course_id: id1, student_id: id2)
@enrolls.each do |enrol|
   if enrol.attended == true
       puts Attendance.where(course_id: id1, student_id: id2).count
   end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it, so that the enrollment has access only it's attendances, in the enrollment.rb model?

Comment: please try this `Enrollment.find(course_id: id1, student_id: id2).student.find(id: id2).attendances.where(course_id: id1, student_id: id2).count`